# EnhanceWithin() is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

am trying to populate a list view via ajax and jquery. after i have populated the data. the enhancement doesnt show.

this is what i did.
[Fiddle Result](http://jsfiddle.net/mystro/zmhe575b/1/)

```
var poss_ans = "6,4,8,2";
var possibleAnswers = poss_ans.split(","); //poss_ans is string containing all the answer from the database

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {

    var $posans = $('#poss_ans');    
    for (var i = 0; i < possibleAnswers.length; i++) {
        var label = possibleAnswers[i];
        $radio = $('<li />', {
            id: 'rad' + i,

            text: possibleAnswers[i],
        });
        var $label = ' <li ><a href="#" class="rem">   <h2>Dynamic</h2><p><b>To Peter Griffin</b><p>Ah, Mr. Griffin, Im not quite sure how to say this. Kim Bassinger? Bass singer? Bassinger?</p></a></li>';

        $posans.append($label);
    }     
        $posans.enhanceWithin().closest("fieldset").controlgroup("refresh");

});
```

now in the result pane(inside my fiddle) are two different results. the first result labeled " Static".is what i want to acheive when i receive the data. and the second to the last one is  what am getting instead.
when i inspect the element in the browser there is a new class(ui-link) that is been added to the . i tried to remove it but its not working.

i dont know why the enhanceWithin() is not working. could some please help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the last line to

```
$posans.listview("refresh");
```

API DOC: http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/zmhe575b/2/)**