# Dynamically add elements with ajax and json breaks the page layout

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have a page structured with jquery mobile. If i populate a list with a static code:

```
    <script>
document.write('<ul data-role="listview">');


document.write('<li data-icon="false"><a href="#" id="mortadella"><img src="images/app/prod.jpg"><h2>Sisa</h2><p class="wrap">mortadella affettatagr.120</p><span class="ui-li-count">2,70 €</span></a></li>');
document.write('<li data-icon="false"><a href="#" id="mortadella"><img src="images/app/prod.jpg"><h2>Sisa</h2><p class="wrap">mortadella affettatagr.120</p><span class="ui-li-count">2,70 €</span></a></li>');             



document.write('</ul>');

</script>
```

i get this result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFNBe.png)

Now, i try to do it dinamically, reading from a database with ajax and json.
This is the code:

```
<script>
document.write('<ul data-role="listview">');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'db_to_app_prod.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

document.write('<li data-icon="false"><a href="#" id="mortadella"><img src="images/app/prod.jpg"><h2>Sisa</h2><p class="wrap">mortadella affettatagr.120</p><span class="ui-li-count">2,70 €</span></a></li>');

            }); 

        },
        error: function(){
           output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });


document.write('</ul>');
</script>
```

And this is the result: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qypsk.png)
As you can see, the layout is totally broken now. What happens? Why? How do i fix this to obtain dinamically the first result?

EDIT:
This is another try i did:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
        //Phonegap ready
        onDeviceReady();
    });


    //var output = document.getElementById("output");
    var _ul = document.createElement('ul');

    _ul.setAttribute("data-role", "listview");


    $.ajax({
        url: 'db_to_app_prod.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

                var _li =  document.createElement('li');
                _li.setAttribute("data-icon", "false");
                _li.innerHTML = '<li data-icon="false">'+
                '<a href="" id="'+item.id+'">'+
                '<img src="http://gestisciapp.it/gruppodipalo/images/'+item.img+'">'+
                '<h2>'+item.marca+'</h2>'+
                '<p class="wrap">'+item.descrizione+'</p>'+
                '<span class="ui-li-count">'+item.prezzo+' €</span>'+
                '</a></li>';    

                _ul.appendChild(_li);

            }); 

        },
        error: function(){
           output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("output").appendChild(_ul);

});
```

Comment: This is happening because CSS is not applied on the elements injected dynamically by script. Check this for help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946473/jquery-dynamic-element-styling-not-being-applied

Comment: Never use `document.write` to add/change dynamic context.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev actually if i do the same with appendchild, innerhtml, append, i have the same results.

Comment: @Deep could you write the correct code based on mine?

Comment: In your "dynamic" example you didn't create opening `ul` tag.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev check the edit

Comment: @Deep consider my style is imported in this way: <link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: setup a jsfiddle...

Comment: @Legends i have around 10 file imports bwtween css and js...

Comment: `_li.innerHTML='<li...` you duplicate definition of `_li`. The final structure looks like `<li><li>...</li></li>` which is obviously wrong. Also mixing jquery and DOM code is bad style.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev i have removed the duplicate `<li>` , it's still the same. About mixing jquery and DOM, do you have a better solution? I need to read from database and display results generating html. How can achieve this in other way than the one i used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    .....
    success: function(data, status){
        var _ul = $('<ul />').attr('data-role','listview');
        $.each(data, function(i,item){ 

            $('<li data-icon="false" />')
               .append($('<a href="" id="'+item.id+'" />')
                 .append('<img src="http://gestisciapp.it/gruppodipalo/images/'+item.img+'" />')
                 .append('<h2>'+item.marca+'</h2>')
                 .append('<p class="wrap">'+item.descrizione+'</p>')
                 .append('<span class="ui-li-count">'+item.prezzo+' €</span>')
                )//$('<a />')
            //)//$('<li />') no need sorry
            .appendTo(_ul);   
        });
        $('#output').empty().append(_ul);
    },
....
```

Also `dataType:'json'` not `jsonp`. see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ specification

### Update

Full working code. Works with your sample json.

```
        $.ajax('tony.js?id=' + Math.random(), //fake json which match your structure
            {
                dataType: "json",
                jsonp: "jsoncallback",
                method: 'get',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (data, status) {
                    var _ul = $('<ul />').attr('data-role', 'listview');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $('<li data-icon="false" />')
                           .append($('<a href="" id="' + item.id + '" />')
                             .append('<img src="http://gestisciapp.it/gruppodipalo/images/' + item.img + '" />')
                             .append('<h2>' + item.marca + '</h2>')
                             .append('<p class="wrap">' + item.descrizione + '</p>')
                             .append('<span class="ui-li-count">' + item.prezzo + ' €</span>')
                            )//$('<a />')
                        .appendTo(_ul);
                    });
                    $('#output').empty().append(_ul);
                },
                error: function (xhr, d, s) {
                    $('#output').empty().html(s);
                }
            });
```

### Full Working Example

Tested in Google mobile emulator tool.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getData() {
            $.ajax('tony.js?id=' + Math.random(), //fake json which match your structure
                {
                    dataType: "json",
                    jsonp: "jsoncallback",
                    method: 'get',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        var _ul = $('<ul />').attr('data-role', 'listview');
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $('<li data-icon="false" />')
                               .append($('<a href="" id="' + item.id + '" />')
                                 .append('<img src="http://gestisciapp.it/gruppodipalo/images/' + item.img + '" />')
                                 .append('<h2>' + item.marca + '</h2>')
                                 .append('<p class="wrap">' + item.descrizione + '</p>')
                                 .append('<span class="ui-li-count">' + item.prezzo + ' €</span>')
                                )//$('<a />')
                            .appendTo(_ul);
                        });
                        $('#output').empty().append(_ul).enhanceWithin();//.listview();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, d, s) {
                        $('#output').empty().html(s);
                    }
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getData()">Get Data</button>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it prints nothing now... ?

Comment: if i put json instead of jsonp it fails (i have another simpler ajax that works fine with jsonp). Anyway this code you posted is giving no result at all...can you check?

Comment: the php pages generates this result: `([{"id":"35","marca":"Prova6","descrizione":"descrizione lunga per test andare a capo","prezzo":"1.7","img":"1image.jpg","punto_vendita":"Portici 1,Portici 2,Portici 3,Ercolano 1,Ercolano 2","scadenza":"01\/01","homepage":"0","posizione":"1"},{"id":"17","marca":"Galbani","descrizione":"Galbanino gr. 550","prezzo":"3.29","img":"image.png","punto_vendita":"Portici 1,Portici 2,Portici 3,Ercolano 1,Ercolano 2","scadenza":"01\/01","homepage":"0","posizione":"5"}]);`
basically i'm reading from this jsonencoded string.

Comment: ok it reads from database now. But ...still without style. :S i also tried to edit `$('#output').empty().append(_ul);` to ` $('#output').empty().append(_ul).enhanceWithin();` (i've read .enhanceWithin(); is used on jquery mobile to mantain style) but it's aaaaaaalllll unstyled. Please why is this so difficult?

Comment: Add style/class attributes inside the JS append's. Also in your initial "static" code you add 2 `<a>` with the same id. This is bad. Each element should have unique id inside document. Additionally, I suspect you have CSS rule pointed to this id. Change to class.

Comment: I can't add style and attribs inside js because it's a whole page of css imported by jquery mobile. Here is a problem similar to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218192/enhancewithin-is-not-working

would you be able to adapt that to me? i'm literally going crazy. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It worked. I think some imports gave conflicts . Just a question to be sure: is it secure to leave imports like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>` ? May they disappear from google server?

Thank you for all.

Comment: This is CDN. And this is a kind of guarantee. Use of CDN is considered as good practice.